# Firestore slow offline performance on devices with low RAM

Tags: android, performance, google-cloud-firestore, ram, in-memory-database

I'm developing an Android app to work with a cached database from Firestore.

I ran into a problem after trying to make it work with low-memory devices(devices with 1GB and 2GB of RAM). Queries take forever and take up majority of app-memory - note that I work with a list of around 10.000 documents.
The structure of one document is simple, with 10 string fields.

Here is an example of memory usage from profiler:
https://i.ibb.co/MPd9h5g/profiler.png

I tried making the app work with less data, which makes the performance much quicker. It gets slower with the size of database.

Sync with database-collection from server:

```
FirebaseFirestore client = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
final Query query = client.collection("collection_name").orderBy("name");

ListenerRegistration snapshotListener = query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot querySnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                // success
            }
        });
```

After collection-sync from server(which can take couple of minutes), I am performing queries with enforced cache-source, like this:

```
Source source = Source.CACHE;
client.collection("collection_name")
                .limit(15)
                .whereEqualTo("some_field", "some_value")
                .orderBy("name").get(source);
```

If I enforce it using Source.SERVER, it works just fine. But my goal is to be able to get it from CACHE.

Is there any way to move in-memory-database location to storage, to avoid memory-usage? 
Or any other way to make bigger firestore-database work with low-memory devices without painful loading?

Thank you in advance for your help!